# How can I open the Windows Media Player interface with task scheduler

Tags: windows-7, command-line, scheduled-tasks

Since my waking clock is broken I want to use my computer, and I managed to make it launch a music through task scheduler, but I would like the interface to show when the task is being run, but opening the task manager to kill the process by hand is quite annoying, so I try to also open the GUI to be able to stop the task easily.

Here are a few command lines and tricks I tried :

- `wmpplayer /open /play "mymusic"`
- Creating a bat file launching the music and calling the bat with the task scheduler
- Using `start /B` before my command

Also, using the launch option `/close` is not a solution, I want to be sure I stop the music by myself, cause I could not wake up from listening to the music only once =P

So is there a way to show the interface when the task is being run, or a way to quickly end the task without having to open the task manager and end the process manually?

Comment: I'm curious, I just built a batch file to start WMP through the task scheduler, but it works just fine and starts with  an interface. You mean the program itself doesn't show up?

Or is it the task scheduler interface that you want to have show up?

Comment: Yes, the music is heard, but the windows media player interface doesn't show up. What did you put in your batch file?

Comment: Just having this works fine: 

cd "C:\Program Files\Windows Media Player"
wmplayer.exe /open

Comment: I don't understand, my batch has the command `wmpplayer /open /play "mymusic"` in it and runs fine when launched by hand, but when the batch is launched thourgh task scheduler, the interface doesn't show up

Comment: When you configure your task, in the "general", is the checkbox marked "hidden" checked? If so, uncheck it. If this works, I'll put it in an official answer

Comment: It was not checked, I tried to check/uncheck but nothing has changed :/

Comment: Are you running the script as the same user that is logged in?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44384/discussion-between-dijdkay-and-ironwilliamcash).